# Windows 10 takes over 5 minutes to reach the login screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance

Windows 10 takes over 5 minutes to reach the login screen
How can I speed it up?
I'm using Windows 10 20H2

I have already done `chkdsk`, `dism` and `sfc` and no errors were found. I've also installed windows updates. I've also enabled and disabled `fast startup` in `Power Options` and that also didn't help.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a screenshot of your system specs? Control Panel -> System and then under "System" where it says "Processor", "Installed Memory", etc. If you can't do a screenshot, just text would suffice. Also is this a new issue or has this computer always been like this?

Comment: `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz   1.19 GHz` `8.00 GB  RAM (7.79 GB usable)`, I think the laptop was always like this but I can't remember, but it has got worse with time. Also `GHz` is nowadays no longer an accurate way of judging how fast a processor is.

Comment: This behaviour can happen if there are login/GPO scripts trying to connect to non-accessible drive mappings, printers, etc...failing on login.  Probably not the case unless hosts FQDNs are changed and/or if the scripts are not being maintained.

Comment: How do find such scripts?

Comment: A 10th generation i5 should not be a throttle to Windows 10, but I did just realize you said this is a laptop. A laptop's performance power is greatly affected by whether or not it is running off direct power or the battery. Test the time plugged in vs. unplugged. And if that doesn't make a difference then it could be the speed limit of your drive. You can download a free and trusted read/write speed tester from https://www.userbenchmark.com/ and I'd be interested to see what your speeds are. In my experience I have noticed that a high speed SDD makes a monumental diff. in win10 boot time.

Comment: Also, to touch on desbest's comment about GPO, that's Group Policy and unless this is a company laptop or previously owned, shouldn't be affecting you. For company laptops that have to search for a domain to authenticate your login and apply Group Policy, this would be an issue, but not for a personal laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem now.There was two parts to it.

## Drivers specific to my computer

Firstly, my computer manufacturer, Acer, not only does their website give me outdated drivers on my product page, they also give faulty drivers. If you were to install these faulty drivers, they would fill the computer with junk alongside the current driver that was previously installed at the time of installation. So I went to Windows Settings then Apps then uninstalled the following software, which is strange because drivers shouldn't appear there, only in Device Manager

It was as if drivers had graphical user interfaces and the user could open a window associated with it, even though no such windows existed.

[image: uninstall programs in apps and features in windows settings]

- Intel Serial IO Driver
- Realtek Wireless LAN Driver aka Realtek FE/GbE Family Controller
- Realtek Ethernet Controller Driver
- Intel Chipset Driver

That cut the startup time from 9 minutes to 7 minutes and 30 seconds. I then restarted my computer to finalise the uninstall of the drivers. On windows even if uninstalling a driver doesn't prompt the user to restart, you should still restart anyway, as traces are often left on the computer until a restart happens. But it was still over 5 minutes to reach the login screen.

## Windows Update

Then I was doing [some internet surfing on Ten Forums](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-10-news/179561-kb5000736-featured-update-windows-10-version-21h1-enablement-package.html) and noticed that maybe Windows Update neglected to even bother to fetch some updates for me to install.

Below are Windows Updates to install manually by downloading the file.

The below windows update should **ONLY** be installed on Windows 10 2004

- [Servicing Stack Update KB4577266 for Windows 10 2004 ONLY - KB4577266](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/servicing-stack-update-for-windows-10-version-2004-september-8-2020-7304b509-d6c1-f02b-04c7-0b8c4b9bb746)

You should also install the following 2 windows updates **in the following order**.

- [Servicing Stack Update for Windows 10 2004 and 20H2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/servicing-stack-update-for-windows-10-version-2004-and-20h2-january-12-2021-c8a86bf7-6d49-b7fe-4369-44b1429b33cf)
- [Cumulative Update May 11, 2021 - KB5003173 (OS Build 19041.985 and above) or a later cumulative update](https://support.microsoft.com/help/5003173)

AFTER the above 2 Windows Updates are installed, install **ONE** of the following Windows Update depending on your computer's processor type (or architecture). You either have a 32 bit, 64 bit, or ARM processor.

Direct download links for KB5000736 MSU file from Microsoft Update Catalog:

- [Download KB5000736 MSU for Windows 10 v2004 and v20H2 32-bit (x86) -
  165 KB](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/upgr/2021/03/windows10.0-kb5000736-x86_428ba21ee5118bac619f4de6977de69c1f65b066.msu)
- [Download KB5000736 MSU for Windows 10 v2004 and v20H2 64-bit (x64) - 166 KB](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/upgr/2021/03/windows10.0-kb5000736-x64_880844224a175033802b3d7a1f40ec304c0548dd.msu)
- [Download KB5000736 MSU for Windows 10 v2004 and v20H2 ARM64 - 163 KB](http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/upgr/2021/03/windows10.0-kb5000736-arm64_8ba2303168d4eddb26c8bba069cdc03856ae29be.msu)

After I installed all the relevant windows updates, my startup speed went back to how it was the first day I used the computer, you know, after a clean install after wiping everything out.

Now it takes 2m50s to reach the login screen which is the optimum time.

Answer (score 0):

Open up `msconfig`. On the 'Boot' tab, enable 'Boot log'

[image]

Apply, then reboot.
Open the boot log (`C:\%windir%\ntbtlog.txt`) once you're back into Windows, and review what the time is being spent on.

Comment: Here's my log. https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2040139 How do I know which of these belong to Microsoft Windows and which don't? All the files come from the windows folder. Also there's no timestamps.

Comment: I rejected your edit. To assume c:\windows for the windows directory will raise eyebrows. Annoyingly, the log doesn't have time stamps...